# Sending Multiple Emails using Outlook

Tags: python

I want to write code that sends out emails to multiple clients (individually).

```
address = ['abc@abc.com','def@def.com','ghi@ghi.com','jkl.com@jkl.com']
ticketnumbers = ['1','2','3','4']
```

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
z = 0 
while z < len(address):
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(z)
    z = z + 1

i = 0  
while i < len(address):
    mail.To = address[i]
    mail.Subject = 'SUBJECT'
    mail.Body = '''
Hello,

This is a test message!

Thanks,

JC
''' + ticketnumbers[i]
    
    mail.Send()
    i = i + 1
```

However I keep getting the following error:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqVrw.png]

How would I iterate through the address and the ticketnumbers lists so it's applied to each message individually?

Thanks!

Comment: The contents of your while loop over `z` should all be in the loop over `i`. Here, you create a new item in one iteration and replace it in the next iteration without doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add `;` to  `mail. To` object like below
`mail. To = "someone@mail.com;someone2@mail.com"`
You can put as many mails you want with `;` in python
its works for `mail.CC` also.